# SQL ALTER TABLE SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE) on production server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I need to create a new table which have foreign key with `Users` table.

Users table has 2 millions of records.

When I run script on our test server it locks this table and test users cannot query this table during transaction.

Query starts like;

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
/*CREATE NEW TABLE AND FOREIGN KEYS HERE*/
```

What would be to safe way to run on production without locking it?

Should we set production server in "Maintenance Mode" and set back live again when sql transaction complete?

Comment: That code makes no sense.

Comment: What is the problem with the code? I added comment what is happening in the next statement.

Comment: "I need to create a new table which have foreign key with "Users" table" - so simply create it!

Comment: This is SSMS generated code, so if I make changes on GUI and generate script the code will be this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a new table and its foreign keys, and even the new table indexes, you don't need to lock or set the lock_escalation of the referred table (in your case, dbo.Users). Simply do not run the above transaction, just the new table and foreign keys creation.